# How to use group_contat() function in multiple tables?

Tags: php, mysql

I have records that I want to combine but they are in different columns. I know `group_contat()` will do but I don't know to insert it.

Here is my SQL query:

```
select * from 
info join crew_documents_table on info.id = crew_documents_table.document_crew_id
 join crew_rank on info.crew_rank = crew_rank.crew_rank_id where crew_rank in ('1','2','3','4') 
and crew_status = '$crew_status'
 and vessel = '$vessel_name' and document_status = 'ACTIVE'
```

I expect this kind of result: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4fXHG.jpg

But it gives me many rows for every record

EDIT

Here is my sample of table:

Table info:

```
    id           |  full_name  |crew_rank
    -------------|-------------|------------
    1            |ADRIAN PASCUA|10
    -------------|-------------|------------
    4            |STEPH PASCUA | 10
```

table `crew_documents_table`

```
doc_type   | doc_number | date_issue  | document_crew_id
-----------|----------- |-------------|-----------------
1          | 123456     | 2016/11/11  | 1
-----------|----------- |-------------|-----------------
1          | 642312     | 2016/11/01  | 4
-----------|----------- |-------------|-----------------
2          | 123456     | 2016/11/11  | 1
-----------|----------- |-------------|-----------------
2          | 642312     | 2016/11/01  | 4
```

I need to combine the column `doc_type 1` and `doc_type_2` with the same `document_crew_id`

Comment: in your img there are not values  group_concat  ...

Comment: Can you provide a sample/example of your tables?

Comment: okay. i will edit my post

Comment: i added my tables and what column must be combined

Answer (score 0):

Could be you can use a inner join with a dynamic table with group concat() so you can get all the columns plus the grouped  values

```
  select *, t.grouped
  from info 
  join crew_documents_table on info.id = crew_documents_table.document_crew_id
   join crew_rank on info.crew_rank = crew_rank.crew_rank_id 
   join (
      select document_crew_id, group_concat(doc_type) as  grouped 
      from crew_documents_table
      group by document_crew_id
      ) t on t.document_crew_id = info.id 
  where crew_rank in ('1','2','3','4') 
  and crew_status = '$crew_status'
```

In your query you are using select  *.   this is in contrast with the need  of obtain a group by value

you can try this for check

```
  select distinct info.id, t.grouped
  from info 
  join crew_documents_table on info.id = crew_documents_table.document_crew_id
   oin crew_rank on info.crew_rank = crew_rank.crew_rank_id 
   join (
      select document_crew_id, group_concat(doc_type   ) as  grouped 
      from crew_documents_table
      group by document_crew_id
      ) t on t.document_crew_id = info.id 
  where crew_rank in ('1','2','3','4') 
  and crew_status = '$crew_status'
```

When you need  group by value you have two possibilities  or you join the group by in dynamic table as in my first asnwer or, if each distinct value is not important,  you shoudl reduce the result form the main select using group by and (fake) aggregation function

Comment: can i ask? what is `t` on `t.grouped`? what's that stand for?
sorry for dumb question

Comment: I obtain the group_concat value using the result of a subselect  like a table .. the t is the name of this dinamically generated  table so  . i can join properly  the result from this table to the others using the table name  as alias  and use the column name  ( t.grouped is the grouped  column name from table t) --- hope is clear ..

Comment: i tried your answer but the output is still the same. it does not combine the columns

Comment: You should have a new  column  at the right of your select with grouped value .. (obvisuly this is repated  for each row  ..becuase you query  ... is not grouped  by .. only my result is group  ) .. if you don't see the new column you have some problem irewiriting code ..